# Generating random Key firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, key, google-cloud-firestore

Im running a **FIRESTORE** database, and i want to create a random key with the **same pattern as firestore does**.

In the link i found the function that is called once i create a document
with: 'db.ref.add()' to generate the key in client side:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/73a586c92afe3f39a844b2be86086fddb6877bb7/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L36

I need to do something like this:

```
let key = newId()
console.log(key)
db.ref().doc(key).set(data)
```

Answer (score 11):

it is very easy to use the firestore uid generator:

```
const uid = admin.firestore().collection("tmp").doc().id
```

this would do the trick without requiring to save some data

but in your specific example: if you don't specify any key it will be auto-generated by firestore:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("MY COLLECTION").doc().set(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just use the .add method instead of auto generating a uuid on your own.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```